# How do I concatenate string to an existing file?

Tags: file, append, dart

I've got a text file (it has content in it) and I want to append text to it.
This is my code:

```
File outputFile=new File('hello.out');
      outputFile.createSync();
      List<String> readLines=files[i].readAsLinesSync(Encoding.UTF_8);
      for(int j=0;j<readLines.length;j++)
      {

        outputFile.writeAsStringSync(readLines[j], FileMode.APPEND); }
```

For some reason Dart put a yellow line under "FileMode.APPEND" and it says that it's an "extra argument". However, this link http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/File.html claims that it is optional.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The FileMode is an optional, named parameter, so you have to specify its name ('mode') when you call it. To solve your problem, change this:

```
outputFile.writeAsStringSync(readLines[j], FileMode.append);
```

to this:

```
outputFile.writeAsStringSync(readLines[j], mode: FileMode.append);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) I am new to dart, and I wonder, what is a named parameter?

Comment: @Cheshie read more on that: http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#functions-optional-parameters

Comment: FileMode.APPEND is deprecated now. All FileMode parameters converted to lowercase. Use FileMode.append.

Answer (score 5):

This code is really all you need:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  new File('test.txt').writeAsStringSync('append some more content', mode: FileMode.APPEND);
}
```

Notice that the file mode is a *named parameter*, so you need to specify it as `mode:`.

And as always, use the asynchronous version unless it doesn't matter (cli tools, one-time initialization during start-up, etc.)