# How to write new map with different values into json file without changing key in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, maps

I'm trying to add new content into a json as a map. It should look something like this:-

```
[
    {
        "title":"mon",
        "date":"2/3/2020"
    },
    {
        "title":"tue",
        "date":"3/3/2020"
    },
    {
        "title":"wed",
        "date":"4/3/2020"
    }
]
```

And I want show it in a `listview`. This is the code I use to create, write, and display:-

```
//new class

class WorkersLog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WorkersLogState createState() => _WorkersLogState();
}

class _WorkersLogState extends State<WorkersLog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _showSettingsPanel() {
      showModalBottomSheet(
          isScrollControlled: true,
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .90,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 40.0),
              child: Center(child: WorkerCardData()),
            );
          });
    }

    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 40),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                  "add document to store wages, loans etc of workers save paper,don't lose track of your accounts!"),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(150, 350, 0, 5),
                      child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                        label: Text('add document'),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.save),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('object');
                          _showSettingsPanel();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Create and write file to json

class WorkerCardData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WorkerCardDataState createState() => _WorkerCardDataState();
}

class _WorkerCardDataState extends State<WorkerCardData> {
  TextEditingController title = new TextEditingController();

  File jsonFile;
  Directory dir;
  String fileName = 'myFile.json';
  bool fileExists = false;
  Map<String, dynamic> fileContent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((Directory directory) {
      dir = directory;
      jsonFile = new File(dir.path + '/' + fileName);
      fileExists = jsonFile.existsSync();
      if (fileExists)
        this.setState(
            () => fileContent = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync()));
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    title.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void createFile(
      Map<String, dynamic> content, Directory dir, String fileName) {
    print("Creating file!");
    File file = new File(dir.path + "/" + fileName);
    file.createSync();
    fileExists = true;
    file.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(content));
  }

  void writeToFile(String title, dynamic date) {
    print("Writing to file!");
    Map<String, dynamic> content = {'title': title, 'date': date};
    if (fileExists) {
      print("File exists");
      Map<String, dynamic> jsonFileContent =
          json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
      jsonFileContent.addAll(content);
      jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(jsonFileContent));
    } else {
      print("File does not exist!");
      createFile(content, dir, fileName);
    }
    this.setState(() => fileContent = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync()));
    print(fileContent);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
          new Text(
            "File content: ",
            style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          new Text(fileContent.toString()),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
          new Text("Add to JSON file: "),
          new TextField(
            controller: title,
            decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                hintText: 'title',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.info, color: Colors.white)),
          ),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
          new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("save new document"),
            onPressed: () => writeToFile(title.text, DateTime.now().toString()),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

//display json as list view

class WorkerCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  WorkerCard({this.title});
  @override
  _WorkerCardState createState() => _WorkerCardState();
}

Directory dir;
Map<String, dynamic> workerFileContent;
File workerFile;

class _WorkerCardState extends State<WorkerCard> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((Directory directory) {
      dir = directory;
      workerFile = File(dir.path + 'myFile.json');
      workerFileContent = json.decode(workerFile.readAsStringSync());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(workerFileContent['title'].toString()),
              Text(workerFileContent['date'].toString()),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my problem. Each time I add new title, the file gets overwritten. How do I add a new map to my json file without overwriting previously added content?

Comment: I think you need to use `FileMode.append` when writing to the file. It's a named param, so your writeAsStringSync should have `mode: FileMode.append` if you don't want to overwrite the existing file contents, and instead, want to add to the end of the file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate string to an existing file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012160/how-do-i-concatenate-string-to-an-existing-file)

Comment: How do I implement it in my code? Instead of `addAll` should I use `append`?

Comment: I think in this case, you'll want to read the current contents and convert it to a list (I think you already do this). Then, add the new element to the list. Finally, write the full list back to the file, overwriting existing contents.

Comment: I did this `jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(jsonFileContent),
          mode: FileMode.append);` but I get error```The following FormatException was thrown while handling a gesture:
Unexpected character (at character 51){"title":"ok","date":"2020-09-08 21:50:29.491664"}{"title":"ok","date":"202...
                                                  ^
```

Comment: How to add a coma mark after each map?

Comment: I think by using the FileMode.append, you've made the json file no longer valid json

Comment: to add a comma between a list of strings, you can use the `.join(',')` method to join each string with a comma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221170/discussion-between-loganrussell48-and-illuminate).

Comment: Why does `FileMode.append` make my json invalid?

Comment: It doesn't make it invalid, unless you do. If you have a list of maps, [ {}, {} ], and then add a map to the end of the file, [ {}, {} ] { }, it's no longer valid json. You have to add it *within* the list of the other maps to be like this: [ {}, {}, {} ]

Comment: I got my mistake, now how do I solve it?

Comment: Read the file, as it stands, and convert it to a `List` object. Then, once you have the `List`, call the `.add` method on it to add a new `Map` to the `List`. At this point, you have all the old content of the file, plus the new map is inside the list (because its not in a file yet). So, encode this list, and then write it to the file, overwriting all the content

Comment: Can show how to write the proper function. I'm having trouble grasping it.

Comment: Do I have to create an empty list? Add map to it and then convert it json?

Comment: `List objects = jsonDecode(file.readAsStringSync()) as List;` <- This reads the file as it is, before doing anything, and puts contents in a list. `objects.add(newObject);` <- This adds the new item to the list. Self explanatory. `file.writeAsStringSync(jsonEncode(objects));` <- This writes all the old content, plus the new item, back to the file.

Comment: `The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast` this error is showing up

Comment: a json file will either be a List or a Map. So you should check to make sure that the json file you're decoding is a list or map. It seems like it's reading it as a map, and then you're trying to cast it to a list, which won't be allowed.

Comment: There's is definitely a solution. I've been telling you the solution. I am not implementing the solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> loganrussell48 Thanks for guiding me to the answer

Change:-

`Map<String, dynamic> fileContent;`

To:-

`List fileContent;`